# How to upload mp3 file in php?

Tags: php, mp3

I am trying to upload mp3 file, but when i submit my file it give me error "Notice: Undefined index: audio/mpeg in E:\xampp\htdocs\page_login\mp3.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined offset: 1000000 in E:\xampp\htdocs\page_login\mp3.php on line 8"

## Here is my code

```
 <?php
 include_once("connection.php");
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
 $file_name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
 $file_tmp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $file_type=$_FILES['file']['audio/mpeg'];
 $file_size=$_FILES['file']['1000000'];
 $insert=mysqli_query($connection, "insert into `file`(`audio`)values 
 ('".$file_name."')");
 move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "image/".$file_name);
 echo "file upload";}   
?>
<form action="mp3.php" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<table border="2" width="10%" align="center">
<tr><th><input type="file" name="file"></th>
<th><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></th></tr></table>
</form>
```

Comment: `$file_size=$_FILES['file']['1000000'];`

Comment: Change to $file_size=$_FILES['file']['size']. Also you should consider using prepared SQL statements for security.

Answer (score 2):

Just as the error states, there is no property on a `$_FILES` array entry called `"audio/mpeg"`:

```
$_FILES['file']['audio/mpeg']
```

(It would be pretty weird to have a property with that name on most files.)

There *is*, however, a property called `"type"`:

```
$file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
```

There's also no property called `"1000000"`, but there is one called `"size"`.